# Active Directory description field values not showing up

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis, active-directory

I'm working on getting values from Active Directory from a script task in C# (3.5 framework) in SSIS. The code to accomplish this seems to be working fine. I use a nested loop with the outer loop pulling values that aren't multi-valued and inserting them to a table with a stored procedure, then passing back the PK of that row to be used as a FK in the second loop to a second stored procedure that inserts all the groups that user belongs to in a second table.

My problem is I can't get any values from what I believe should be the `Description` field that should hold the description of each individual group. If I step through it and check the count of description object, it shows 0. Using the same code to check the count of `Memberof` I get the number of groups that user belongs to. The other part that I don't understand is I get values from the `Description` field in the outer loop, but its closer to that of comments of the user record, not descriptions of the individual groups. Its as if my `Description` is not multivalued. But someone else can confirm through the AD portal that the `Description` field has values that describe what each group is. I'm kind of stumped. See code below.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP:[my address]");
DirectorySearcher Dsearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
Dsearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=User))"; 

foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in Dsearch.FindAll())
{
    (code continues from original post)

    using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection([mysqlconnection]))
    {
        using (SqlCommand dataCommand = dataConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
           dataCommand.CommandText = "ActiveDirectory.InsertParentRecords";
           dataCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PackageLogId", Dts.Variables["PackageLogId"].Value.ToString());
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cn", GetProperty(sResultSet, "cn"));
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@givenName", GetProperty(sResultSet, "givenName"));
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@initials", GetProperty(sResultSet, "initials"));
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sn", GetProperty(sResultSet, "sn"));

           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", GetProperty(sResultSet, "mail"));
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", GetProperty(sResultSet, "Name"));
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleName", GetProperty(sResultSet, "middleName"));
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", GetProperty(sResultSet, "title"));
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeID", GetProperty(sResultSet, "employeeID"));

           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeNumber", GetProperty(sResultSet, "employeeNumber"));
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objectSid", ConvertSidToString((byte[])sResultSet.Properties["objectSid"][0]));
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userAccountControl", tempuserAccountControl);
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@whenCreated", GetProperty(sResultSet, "whenCreated"));
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@distinguishedName", GetProperty(sResultSet, "distinguishedName"));

           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@badPasswordTime", Convert.ToString(badPasswordTime));  //Issues!!
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@badPwdCount", GetProperty(sResultSet, "badPwdCount"));
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberof", GetProperty(sResultSet, "memberof"));
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@samaccountname", GetProperty(sResultSet, "samaccountname"));
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", GetProperty(sResultSet, "Description"));

           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maxPwdAge", GetProperty(sResultSet, "maxPwdAge"));   //Issues!!                               
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwdLastSet", pwdLastSet);   //Issues!!
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LockOutTime", Convert.ToString(LockOutTime));     //Issues!!

           if (disabled == false)  //Issues!!
              dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Acctdisabled", '0');
           else
              dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Acctdisabled", '1');

           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@displayname", GetProperty(sResultSet, "displayname"));

           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@twofactor", twofactor);
           dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skiprecord", skiprecord);

           dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@DetailID", SqlDbType.Int);
           dataCommand.Parameters["@DetailID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

           dataConnection.Open();
           dataCommand.ExecuteScalar();
           dataConnection.Close();

           Counter++;
           DetailID = (int)dataCommand.Parameters["@DetailID"].Value;
       }
    }

    using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection[mysqlconnection]))
    {
       using (SqlCommand dataCommand = dataConnection.CreateCommand())
       {
           dataConnection.Open();

           int groupCount = sResultSet.Properties["memberOf"].Count;
           int DescriptionCount = sResultSet.Properties["Description"].Count;

           for (int counter = 0; counter < groupCount; counter++)
           {
               dataCommand.CommandText = "ActiveDirectory.InsertMemberOf";
               dataCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

               dataCommand.Parameters.Clear();
               dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PackageLogId", Dts.Variables["PackageLogId"].Value.ToString());
               dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DetailID", DetailID);

               if (sResultSet.Properties.Contains("Description"))
               {
                  dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Group", sResultSet.Properties["Description"][counter].ToString());
               }
               else
               {
                  dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Group", "n/a");
               }                               

               dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberOf", sResultSet.Properties["memberOf"][counter]);   

               dataCommand.ExecuteScalar();
               InnerCounter++;
            }
         }  //End of DataCommand
     }  //End of Data Connection 


     Debug.WriteLine(GetProperty(sResultSet, "displayname") + "  " + Counter + ",  " + InnerCounter + ",  " + GetProperty(sResultSet, "userAccountControl"));
     InnerCounter = 0;                        
  } //End of For Each Loop
```

Comment: Added code to show how sResultSet is populated in edit, @billinkc

Comment: Can you connect with ADSI Edit http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354(v=ws.10).aspx and verify for yourself what is in that field?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet (not at work anymore), but I did have someone go through AD Portal to verify Description is being per group name

Comment: I find it often saves me a lot of effort to be absolutely certain

Comment: I have to accomplish this without installing the software.  I don't have persmissions to install anything on my PC, and by the time my permissions are elevated, I would have hoped to have found a work around.

Answer (score 1):

A LDAP Search query is a bit like a SQL query, I know It's not clearly documented but you'd better declare the properties you want to be retrived by the search. Can you try to add

```
DirectorySearcher Dsearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
...
Dsearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
...
Dsearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=User))";
```

In my code I really add all the properties I need. I agree it works without that most of the time, but just most of the time.