# C# to Active Directory getting User / Group / Description

Tags: c#, active-directory

This is a related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462764/active-directory-description-field-values-not-showing-up) where I'm attempting to do the same thing.  Because I couldn't get it to work, I'm trying a different methodology. My goal is to get all users in a collection and loop through the collection loading paramaters for a stored procedure simular to pervious post.

This time I'm trying the AccountManagement Class  Again, I can get all the attributes of the user, but this time I don't know the syntax to get the groups or descriptions of the groups.  I assume that I need to simply load some type of collection that comes off the UserPrincipal such as `up.GetGroups()` and enumerate through that but I'm struggling with syntax.  With that code, I also need what would get me access to description.

```
            PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "[my domain", "[my path]");
            UserPrincipal ADUser = new UserPrincipal(AD);
            PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher();
            ps.QueryFilter = ADUser;

            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> result = ps.FindAll();

            foreach (Principal p in result)
                using (UserPrincipal up = (UserPrincipal)p)
                {

                    if (up.AccountExpirationDate.HasValue)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.AccountExpirationDate.ToString());
                    if (up.AccountLockoutTime.HasValue)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.BadLogonCount.ToString());
                    if (up.DisplayName != null)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.DisplayName.ToString());
                    if (up.DistinguishedName != null)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.DistinguishedName.ToString());
                    if (up.EmailAddress != null)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.EmailAddress.ToString());
                    if (up.EmployeeId != null)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.EmployeeId.ToString());
                    if (up.Enabled.HasValue)
                        if (up.Enabled == true)
                            Debug.WriteLine("User is active");
                        else
                            Debug.WriteLine("User is deactivated");
                    if (up.GivenName != null)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.GivenName.ToString());
                    if (up.LastBadPasswordAttempt.HasValue)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.LastBadPasswordAttempt.ToString());
                    if (up.LastLogon.HasValue)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.LastLogon.ToString());
                    if (up.LastPasswordSet.HasValue)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.LastPasswordSet.ToString());
                    if (up.MiddleName != null)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.MiddleName.ToString());
                    if (up.Name != null)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.Name.ToString());
                    if (up.PasswordNeverExpires != null)
                        if (up.PasswordNeverExpires == true)
                            Debug.Print("User Password Never Expires");
                        else
                            Debug.WriteLine("User Password Expires");
                    if (up.SamAccountName != null)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.SamAccountName.ToString());
                    if (up.Sid != null)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.Sid.ToString());
                    if (up.Surname != null)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.Surname.ToString());
                    if (up.UserPrincipalName != null)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.UserPrincipalName.ToString());
                    if (up.VoiceTelephoneNumber != null)
                        Debug.WriteLine(up.VoiceTelephoneNumber.ToString());

                }
```

I attempted to use the `GroupPrincipal` but as it is written, I can see Description field but I can't see anything else.  I attempted that code with:

```
     //PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "[my domain]", "[my path]");
            GroupPrincipal theGroup = new GroupPrincipal(AD);
            PrincipalSearcher gps = new PrincipalSearcher(theGroup);
            foreach (var found in gps.FindAll())
            {
                if (found.Description != null)
                {                       
                    Debug.WriteLine(found.Description.ToString());
                }
                if (found.DisplayName != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(found.DisplayName.ToString());
                }                    
            }
```

This code works fine to get the Description of groups, but I can't see anything else because all other fields are null.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What else do you want from a group aside from the name & description?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need all the fields that are listed above in the first block of code.  Inaddition to the problem I have, it seems that even if I solve the problem from this post, some of those fields will not be available in UserPrincipal.  I will have to use some type of mix between UserPrincipal with 'ExtensionGet' method.  I don't know that much about it but I've seen others talk about how they solved it in other post and I will cross that bridge when I get there hopefully.

Comment: Half the stuff you listed for users isn't applicable to groups and will just be null and the rest of it is never really used anyway and will still be null. I believe there is nothing wrong with your code, your problem is simply that none of that information exists for your groups.

Comment: @Ashigore, I'm sure I encountered that problem in my answer.  The biggest thing I couldn't find or didn't know was `PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> userGroups = CurrentUser.GetGroups();`because I didn't know how to get to the groups each user belonged to. Once I got that I was fine and could work out the rest.  But the problem you mentioned still exists and I'm still working to find that solution.  Either way, I still needed this code to get to the next step which I will hopefully work out very soon.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believed I solved the problem to this post.  Below is code that fills a object from Active Directory and enters a nested loop.  The first loops through each user and the second loops through each group that user belongs to before moving to the next user.  Within each loop, I'm passing parameters to stored procedures that performs insert statements with the values to two sepearate tables, one for the user attributes and the second for the group attributes. The first stored procedure passes back the identity of each row to be used as a FK in the second table.

For some of the parameters are the words "NotFoundYet" because UserPrincipal doesn't have those fields available like `DirectorySearcher` had on my first attempt at writing this.  This also answers my question from [Active Directory description field values not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462764/active-directory-description-field-values-not-showing-up) , also posted by me.

Technically, I still need code to find those missing attributes, but I though this might help someone else while I'm still trying find what I don't have.  I'll update later.  Special thanks to Jeff Ronay for the help on this.

```
    PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "[my domanin]", "[my path]");
            UserPrincipal ADUser = new UserPrincipal(AD);
            PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher();
            ps.QueryFilter = ADUser;

            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> result = ps.FindAll();

            foreach (UserPrincipal CurrentUser in result)
            {

                PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> userGroups = CurrentUser.GetGroups();


            using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection("[my sql connection]"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand dataCommand = dataConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    dataCommand.CommandText = "ActiveDirectory.InsertParentRecords";
                    dataCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PackageLogId", Dts.Variables["PackageLogId"].Value.ToString());
                    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cn", "NotFoundYet");

                    if (CurrentUser.GivenName != null)
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@givenName", CurrentUser.GivenName.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@givenName", "Empty");
                    }

                    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@initials", "NotFoundYet");

                    if (CurrentUser.Surname != null)
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sn", CurrentUser.Surname.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sn", "Empty");
                    }

                    if (CurrentUser.EmailAddress != null)
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", CurrentUser.EmailAddress.ToString());                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", "Empty");                        
                    }

                    if (CurrentUser.Name != null)
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", CurrentUser.Name.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Empty");
                    }

                    if (CurrentUser.MiddleName != null)
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleName", CurrentUser.MiddleName.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleName", "N/A");
                    }

                    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", "NotFoundYet");

                    if (CurrentUser.EmployeeId != null)
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeID", CurrentUser.EmployeeId.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeID", "Empty");    
                    }

                    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeNumber", "NotFoundYet");

                    if (CurrentUser.Sid != null)
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objectSid", CurrentUser.Sid.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objectSid", "Empty");
                    }

                    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userAccountControl", "NotFoundYet" );
                    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@whenCreated", "NotFoundYet");

                    if (CurrentUser.DistinguishedName != null)
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@distinguishedName", CurrentUser.DistinguishedName.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@distinguishedName", "Empty");
                    }

                    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@badPasswordTime", "NotFoundYet");  //Issues!!

                    if (CurrentUser.BadLogonCount != null)
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@badPwdCount", CurrentUser.BadLogonCount.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@badPwdCount", "Empty");
                    }

                    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberof", "Empty");

                    if (CurrentUser.SamAccountName != null)
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@samaccountname", CurrentUser.SamAccountName.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@samaccountname", "Empty");
                    }

                    if (CurrentUser.Description != null)
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", CurrentUser.Description.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", "Empty");
                    }

                    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maxPwdAge", "NotFoundYet");   //Issues!!                               

                    if (CurrentUser.LastPasswordSet != null)
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwdLastSet", CurrentUser.LastPasswordSet.ToString());   //Issues!!
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwdLastSet", "Empty");   //Issues!!
                    }

                    if (CurrentUser.AccountLockoutTime != null)
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LockOutTime", CurrentUser.AccountLockoutTime.ToString());     
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LockOutTime", "Empty");     //Issues!!
                    }

                    if (CurrentUser.Enabled == false)  //Issues!!
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Acctdisabled", '0');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Acctdisabled", '1');
                    }

                    if (CurrentUser.DisplayName != null)
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@displayname", CurrentUser.DisplayName.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@displayname", "Empty");
                    }

                    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@twofactor", "NotFoundYet");     //Calculated from another field     

                    dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@DetailID", SqlDbType.Int);
                    dataCommand.Parameters["@DetailID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    dataConnection.Open();
                    dataCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                    dataConnection.Close();

                    Counter++;
                    DetailID = (int)dataCommand.Parameters["@DetailID"].Value;

                }  //End of Datacommand

            }  //End of Sql Connection



            using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection("[my sql connection]"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand dataCommand = dataConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    dataConnection.Open();

                    foreach (Principal group in userGroups)
                    {

                        dataCommand.CommandText = "ActiveDirectory.InsertMemberOf";
                        dataCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        dataCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PackageLogId", Dts.Variables["PackageLogId"].Value.ToString());
                        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DetailID", DetailID);

                        if (group.Description != null)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(group.Description.ToString());
                            dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupDescription", group.Description.ToString());                                
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupDescription", "Empty");                                
                        }

                        if (group.Name != null)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(group.Name.ToString());
                            dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberOf", group.Name.ToString());                                
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberOf", "Empty");                                
                        }

                        dataCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                        InnerCounter++;                                                        

                    }  //End of 'For Each Principle'

                }//End of DataCommand

            }  //End of Data Connection

        }   //End of 'For Each User' Loop
```

Comment: I rewrote this code to use functions to check for null values, but in general all is the same.